# Is AngularJS compatible with Odoo?

Tags: angularjs, rest, odoo-10

I want to create a new module in **Odoo 10.0** .

In that module there is many requests to another web application using **Restful calls**.

Is **AngularJS** compatible with Odoo? I want to use it to handle requests and pass data from response to the **view**

Comment: [**This link**](https://github.com/akretion/angular-odoo) may interest you.

Comment: thank you it's really interesting

Comment: As it helps you, I posted it has an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is: *not really*.

> Odoo is not HTTP friendly: every request shoud be POST, session_id
>   should be added in the body, there some other stuff which should be
>   added in each request...

---

[**This module**](https://github.com/akretion/angular-odoo) developed by akretion provide you a way to call Odoo webservices from AngularJS.

I think it may solve your issue.

Comment: I want to use AngularJS to customize a module in odoo by sending requests to another application not to send requests to odoo and get response